# is there a way to modify the contents of an HTML tag that is inside a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js and haven't yet understood it.
So I was wondering if there is a way in which I can make my custom Vue component(UnorderedList) manipulate the content that is inside my custom component(UnorderedList)

if I have some `<p>` tags inside my component like this :

```
<UnorderedList :dashed="true">
     <p>some sentence here</p>
     <p>some sentence here</p>
</UnorderedList>
```

then this is what it would look like when the page renders

```
some sentence here
some sentence here
```

What I want my component here to do, is add a "**-**" before every `<p>` tag, so that when the page renders it should look like this :

```
- some sentence here
- some sentence here
```

This is my UnorderedList.vue right now

```
<template>
  <ul >
    <span v-if="dashed">-</span>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'UnorderedList',
  props: {
    dashed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

This above code obviously doesn't work the way I want it to.

So, basically I want to add a "**-**" before everything that is inside the custom component (UnorderedList).

How can I do this ?

I apologize in advance if this is a silly question

Comment: You can use a normal `<ul>` with the [list-style-type css rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type): `list-style-type: '-';`. You'd also need to replace the `<span>` with `<li>`

Comment: @kemp, Thanks for replying so quickly but I need to have this custom component as I might be adding other attributes to it, so is there a way I can somehow manipulate the content ?

Comment: Are you passing the list to the component as a slot or as a prop? Your first example shows a slot, but the second shows a prop (but it's missing?)

Answer (score 1):

you can use vue Filters

```js
            Vue.filter('dash', function (value) {
              if (!value) return ''
              value = `- ${value}`;
              return value;
            })


            var app = new Vue({
                      el: '#app',
                      data: {
                        message: 'Hello Vue!'
                      }
                    })
```

```html
<div id="app">
        {{message | dash}}
</div>
```

after you created filter you can use it in html template like above (message | dash )